# Get the names of users to display in irssi window?

Tags: irc, irssi

By default I can't see the names of the people in the chat unless I do `/names`. How can I always have the names displayed, on the right of the screen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Irssi does not have this built-in, but you can try the [nicklist.pl](http://scripts.irssi.org/scripts/nicklist.pl) script. Download it to ~/.irssi/scripts, use `/script load nicklist` and [read the docs](http://wouter.coekaerts.be/site/irssi/nicklist).